# php how to split a string into array elements?

Tags: php, arrays

We have rows:

```
1 test1
<br> 
2 test2
<br> 
3 test3
<br> 
4 test4
```

For explode in array we test next:

```
$ArrText = explode("\n",$text);
$ArrText = explode("<br>",$text);
```

But it not worked.

Tell me please how to split a string into array elements ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ArrText = explode("\n<br>\n",$text);
```

Two things:

1. You have to split by a new line followed by a `<br>` followed by a new line
2. [Escape characters only work in double quotes, not single ones](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

Comment: Try my updated answer and also try using `\r\n' instead of `\n, too

Comment: Try `\r\n` instead of `\n`